# Nonnegative functions and Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable and $h: \mathbb{R} → [0,∞)$ a nonnegative function. Why is h(X) also a random variable?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the identity from $\mathbf{R}$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure and let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}$ that isn't Lebesgue mesurable and note $h$ be its indicator function.

The function $h$ is non negative and $h(X) = h$ is not a measurable function as $A$ is not measurable, so that $h(X)$ is not a random variable.

Comment: The modification needed is to assume $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a **measurable** function, meaning that $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x)\leq y\}$ is Borel-measurable for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\{h(X)\leq y\} \iff X \in \{x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x)\leq y\}$$ and (since $X$ is a random variable) we can evaluate the probablity that it lies in a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$.